# Prevent chrome console from processing javascript until I'm finished writing it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way I can set up javascripting in Chrome's console so that it does not process my statement as soon as I hit return. If I'm trying to test something out by just writing some javascript there, it processes before I'm done writing.

```
//here I am writing in the console

if ($(el).size() === 0){
   //now I hit return because I want to type some stuff if this evaluates to true
   //but return submits it as a finished piece of javascript and of course 
   //I get SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input before I can have a chance
   //to finish the logic
```

I know I can hit <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> and get a line break, and though that's a small inconvenience, it's still a bit of an inconvenience. Is there anyway I can tell it to hold off processing until I hit a macro like  <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>?

It's the same way in Firebug. Maybe there's an option there. Or maybe someone knows of a good third party add-on. Thanks.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35487

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the comments I posted the [ticket](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35487) for the request for support, but it has been there for awhile. Chrome does have snipplets, but you have to enable them.

1. In the address bar type `about:flags`
2. Enable `Developer Tools experiments`
3. Restart the browser
4. Open the Developer Tools open the settings menu [gear on bottom right corner]
5. Click the Experiments tab [on left], check Snippets support
6. Restart the browser
7. In the Scripts panel, there will be a `Snippets` tab, click on it.
8. Right click on the area below and from context menu select New
9. You can than Edit and Run the code like a file. Run it with the context menu or play button.

Comment: This is massively helpful. Thank you so much, exactly what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 2):

A multi-line console effectively lets you do what you want.  Chrome has a [request](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35487) for this but is otherwise not really available.

[Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/) for Chrome does allow it.  Just click the little red button at the bottom-right of the Javascript console.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Comment: Since the OP asked about Firebug, it's probably worth mentioning also that it works the same in Firebug for Firefox as it does in Firefox Lite.

Comment: @apsillers Yeah I thought about that, but OP seems to be using Chrome, which does not have Firebug available.

Comment: I took "It's the same way in Firebug" to mean "in Firefox", but you're right -- there's no other indication that OP is asking about Firefox beyond the absence of "Lite". Anyway, I suppose it's obvious enough regardless.

Comment: @GrailsGuy I was talking about Firebug. I didn't try it in firebug light, but will check this out. Thank you